# Uber Deeplinking on iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I am trying to generate a deep link that will open the app, set pickup location to current location and dropoff address to Uber's HQ.

Here is what I have:

uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103

Unfortunately, no destination address is being pre-filled once in the app.

Comment: For those that want to experiment, the Uber API Deep Linking docs are: [here](https://developer.uber.com/v1/deep-linking/).  (And at first glance, OP's URL looks reasonable.)

Comment: Thanks Darren, this is where I got the deep linking structure from, but there it does not look it is working. Also, I haven't found a way to test whether the destination address was pre-filled without requesting a Uber and canceling, which makes the testing process less than ideal.

Comment: I would also direct you to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129220/uber-ios-app-url-scheme

Comment: This also fails for me. I don't think that this works. It seems that the Uber iOS app is rejecting the parameters and just showing the default pickup location to be your current location.

Comment: @Romain Did you solve the issue? I have the same problems.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I was running into the same problem and this is the way I got it to work. First, you need to add your client id to the url. So in your case change

```
uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103
```

to

```
uber://?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103
```

where YOUR_CLIENT_ID is the client id given to you by Uber.

To get a client id you must register your app with Uber at https://developer.uber.com/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using the same url pattern (client_id and formatted_address) as you, but it's still doesn't work. When I use lat and lon instead of formatted address everything works.
Do you know any other reasons why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Visput i am also using the same Deeplinking Url, but it only launches uber app not the mobile website in the absence of Uber app ? Can you please tell me how to launch the mobile website also

Comment: @VladPapko : Hi, What exact keys did you use instead of (client_id and formatted_address)..Can you show me your url?

Comment: @Ishika, here is the code I ended up which worked for me: `NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uber://?client_id=%@&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=%f&dropoff[longitude]=%f&dropoff[nickname]=%@",
                                                     @"<Uber client id>",
                                                     37.24,
                                                     52.34,
                                                     @"<Destination Name>"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];`

Answer (score 0):

The dropoff address will show appear once the user drops a pin to select their pickup location.