# Which are the required parameters for Uber app deep linking?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking, uber-api

So I'm trying to implement a deep link to the Uber app from my WebView app. I have read the [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking) and some of the [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049950/uber-deeplinking-on-ios?lq=1) but it's not clear to me which parameters are actually required and which are optional?

I have managed to launch the app but I can't get the dropoff location marked using the below link. Do I need to enter the `product_id`? I want the user to pick this in the app and avoid having to use other Uber api's.

```
"uber://?client_id=" + client_id + "=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=" + dropOffLat + "&dropoff[longitude]=" + dropOffLng,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mandatory parameters are similar to the [POST /v1/requests](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests#section-resource) API endpoint, which are: start_latitude and start_longitude or start_place_id.

For deep linking the mandatory parameters are: action=setPickup, client_id, pickup[latitude] and pickup[longitude] or pickup=my_location

All the others can be chosen by the user in the Uber app.

You can see some examples of deep link URIs in the test resources available in the [rides-android-sdk](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/tree/master/sdk/src/test/resources/deeplinkuris) and how they are used in the [RequestDeeplinkTest](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/blob/master/sdk/src/test/java/com/uber/sdk/android/rides/RequestDeeplinkTest.java)