# Open uber from my app with pickup and dropoff location prefilled without using sdk

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I want to open uber from click of button in my app with pickup and dropoff location prefilled without using uber sdk. I followed the link which suggest deep linking but its not working : https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction

Below given is my code

Firstly added uber as in here:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>uber</string>
    </array>
```

Then added this piece of code in button action:

```
let url = NSURL(string:
 "uber://?client_id=oR5_kM9B8Hsxf9BKAXZl7Pm6IcL38n9w&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=Coit%20Tower&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d&link_text=View%20team%20roster&partner_deeplink=partner%3A%2F%2Fteam%2F9383")

         if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL){
             UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
         }
```

I also just simply tried to open uber from my app, even that is not working. Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No console output ? Does `canOpenURL(_:)` return true ?

Comment: yes..it returns true..my if block is executed

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570664/2124535, the comment from "Vlad Papko" (and use URL instead of NSURL)

Comment: @nathan Yes i have looked up that too, i have also registered my app on uber developer account and client id is there in my url

Comment: As I said, the comment from "Vlad Papko", not the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152813/discussion-between-ishika-and-nathan).

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: @Ishika `openURL:` is depricated in iOS 10: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/    Theoretically this shouldn't prevent it from working, but just in case.

Comment: @thedp I uses the method suggested:
It prints --> Open uber://: false

Comment: @Ishika well, at least now it's consistent with the result, the app doesn't open.

Comment: @Ishika have you tried opening other apps? Do they open?

Comment: I tried Whatsapp.. Even that is not opening :(

Comment: There is an option to use deep link generator available at Uber documentation: https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink. This will give you proper format of the deep link.

Comment: I even tried that. Only i can do is pass itunes url and direct user to appstore. From there the open but i want it to be direct and its not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>uber</string>
    </array>


let url = URL(string:
            "uber://?client_id=oR5_kM9B8Hsxf9BKAXZl7Pm6IcL38n9w&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=Coit%20Tower&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d&link_text=View%20team%20roster&partner_deeplink=partner%3A%2F%2Fteam%2F9383")

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!){
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                    if success  {
                        print("Successfully open uber")
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
 } else{
            print("app not found")
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Salman. The solution worked for me. Also, when some liitle change as I have updated.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for making my life easy.